# Does squeezing image height/width distort true image scale?

Tags: map-making

My issue is specifically that I am making a map, but I am planning to use it in the digital format, where I am only limited to let say 1870x860 in size per map. The issue is that when I prepare the continental map, it does not fit in the aforementioned standard, so I may squeeze the image and it would fit, although  alot of details will also be damaged from that, but that's another issue.

By squeezing I mean using height/width adjustments so that the map image would fit in the form prepared for it.

My question, however, is, does squeezing the image actually ruins or otherwise distorts the SCALE of the map in terms of scale accuracy in the overall scale-setting/mapmaking practice? Let's say, my map is scaled to **represent** 10 miles per inch, would squuezing its **physical image** height/width somehow intervene with that and give a bad/wrong result in scale? Does it matter scale accuracy-wise if the continent is accurately presented on the map in terms of its actual shape? Why?

Comment: Are you altering the height and the width at a different rate?

Comment: Or, to ask it in different words, do you maintain aspect ratio?

Comment: If you have a bar scale on your map (and you should), it will squeeze proportionally to the entire map, and it should be a non-issue. However, if you rely on the physical units (like inches), all depends on your media (screen, print etc.) resolution. You should not rely on physical units unless you have full control over media.

Comment: "Miles to the inch" has meaning only when you print the image on paper. When the map is represented as a raster image it make much more sense to speak of miles per pixel (or pixels per mile, of course).

Comment: I wonder what is the justification for 'Too Story Based' close votes. It seems like the least fitting reason for the closure.  @Mapp I am not sure that your question in its current form is within the scope of the WB.SE. Map-making is potentially on topic, but as it is now your question appears to be a technical question about image scaling and aspect ratio (therefore, I will vote to close as off-topic). Would you mind editing your query and clarifying your goals and how they are related to your fictional world?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will

Your scale will change according to how much you alter the size of your map. Say you shrink it 50%. The original scale was 622,500:1 (10 miles to the inch), you now have 622,500:5/10 or 1,245,000:1 (or 20 miles to the inch)